# Broken font path in CSS causing session value error

Tags: css, laravel, session, font-awesome

I encountered and fixed the strangest issue I have ever faced in my programming career that I wanted to post here in case it helps anyone else (or me again!) in the future.

```
session()->put('keywords', $value);
```

Was being overwritten with `fonts/fontawesome webfont.ttf` - on every new page load rather than keeping the value set.

Comment: Have you added this as an [issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues)?

Answer (score 0):

When I investigated it was the main CSS file being included on the page causing the issue. Looking further and the path to my fontawesome library was incorrect.

As soon as the path was fixed the session value persisted.

I'm still not entirely sure how this technically happened